# microsoft excel fill bottom quarter of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am doing autonomous maintenance at my plant. For this I want to use the following color code in the cells of my excel file:

[image]

The premise is that I fill in the yellow part when they have to do a task or not and that they fill in the other three depending on whether they did the task and other conditions.

I was able to create the borders inside a cell. But I am not able to fill the bottom triangle in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fill a CELL in this way.

You can fill using solid colours or a pattern.

To do so. Right click a CELL or RANGE of CELLs,

Right Click and Select Format Cells.

Here you can see all available fill options.

[image]

You can allo use Conditional Formatting, to Fill a cell based on a condition, however the options available are no different from abve